# It is possible to run GitHub Workflow Actions in an Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, github-actions

As I understand, a GitHub action can also be executed by a (Linux) Docker image to perform a certain task.

For example this GitHub action `Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview` uses Docker image `mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/staticappsclient:stable` to deploy the project to an Azure Static Web App.

Is there a way to call/execute/run this Docker image in a YAML DevOps Pipeline?

Comment: I'd rate it as "unlikely", although I admittedly haven't tried. Looks like an interesting project you could work on.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below update? Please let me if it helped you to fix this issue

Comment: Yes, your information in the answer and the link to the workaround (which I already found, but not followed because it looked like a workaround) did fix the issue for me to be able to install dotnet using sudo commands. However the `mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/staticappsclient:stable` still doesn't work, I've created an issue for that (https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/938 & https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/945).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Container jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops) in Azure devops pipeline is probably what you are looking for.

When you specify a container in your pipeline, the agent will first fetch and start the container. Then, each step of the job will run inside the container. So you can set the Docker image as the container. See below example:

To [run a job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#single-job) in a container:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'

container: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/staticappsclient:stable

steps:
- script: printenv
```

To run a [certain task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#step-target) in a container:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: staticappsclient
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/staticappsclient:stable

steps:
- task: SampleTask@1
  target: host
- task: AnotherTask@1
  target: staticappsclient  # this task will run in the container
```

Update:

To run sudo command inside a container without sudo preinstalled. You can checkout below steps:

1, Name the container by defining the `--name` parameter in Option `options: "--name ci-container -v /usr/bin/docker:/tmp/docker:ro"`

2, Add a script task on top of your yaml pipeline to install the `sudo`

```
- script: |
      /tmp/docker exec -t -u 0 ci-container \
      sh -c "apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" -y install sudo"
```

3, Run the scripts to Install dotnet 3.1 in the following script task: See below full yaml example:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: staticappsclient
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/staticappsclient:stable
    options: "--name ci-container -v /usr/bin/docker:/tmp/docker:ro"

container: staticappsclient

steps:
- script: |
      /tmp/docker exec -t -u 0 ci-container \
      sh -c "apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" -y install sudo"
   
  
- script: |
    
    wget -O - https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.asc.gpg
    
    sudo mv microsoft.asc.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
    wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list
    sudo mv prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
    sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg
    sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
    
    sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
    sudo apt-get update && \
    sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

See [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2043) for more information.

Comment: Hello @levi-lu-msft, thanks for pointing to this direction.
However in this specific situation, I just use CmdLine@2 task to execute some commands inside the container, however executing 'sudo' commands fails. Do you know why?

Comment: @StefHeyenrath The steps were executed under account `vsts_azpcontainer` which is granted SUDO privilege and allow it run any command without authentication. Could you try using bash task instead fo cmdline task?

Comment: Hello @levi-lu-msft. I'm trying to run 'StaticSitesClient' command, however that fails with https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/938
So I tried to install dotnet manually in the (Debian) container, however the "mv" command fails with `mv: cannot create regular file '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg': Permission denied`

Comment: @StefHeyenrath It seems like a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2043). However, you can fix it using above workaround. See above update.